# Oracle SQL nested case with SELECT returns single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle, select, case

I am trying to retrieve values from abcdef table in nested case, I get 'single-row subquery returns more than one row' error in SELECTS MENTIONED ---- error here.
case 1 : when colC value in NOT NULL and when doesn't have  values ('LM','OP','QR'), when colD IS NULL else colD values is between '00'and '99'
case 2:  when colC value in NOT NULL and when does have  values ('LM','OP','QR'), when colD is NULL return that row or when colE is null return that row

How can I rewrite this query to get correct result

```
Table abcdef
colfKEY | colA | colB | colC | colD | colE

Table maintable
colPKEY | colTemp

select 
a.colA , a.colB, a.colC,
CASE  
    WHEN a.colC IS NULL THEN ''    
    WHEN a.colC IS NOT NULL THEN 
       (CASE  
         WHEN  (a.colC NOT IN ('LM','OP','QR')) THEN
          (CASE WHEN (a.colD IS NULL) THEN 
            (SELECT T.colD FROM abcdef T where T.colD IS NULL)   ---- error here
          WHEN TT.colD IS NOT NULL THEN 
           (SELECT TT.colD from abcdef TT WHERE (TT.colD < '00') OR (TT.colD  > '99') )  ---- error here 
          END)

        WHEN (a.colC  IN ('LM','OP','QR')) THEN
       (CASE WHEN a.colD IS NULL THEN 
             (SELECT a.colD FROM abcdef a) ---- error here
         WHEN a.colE IS NULL THEN 
            (SELECT a.colE FROM abcdef a) ---- error here
        END )
        END)
END
from abcdef a where
a.colfKEY IN
(SELECT m.colPKEY FROM maintable m where 
m.colTemp= '999999');
```

Comment: Your subquery returns more than 1 record. Try `and rownum=1` in where clause if you are fine with any record from subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the query without subqueries :

```
SELECT a.colA,
       a.colB,
       a.colC,
       CASE
         WHEN a.colC IS NULL THEN
          ''
         WHEN a.colC IS NOT NULL THEN
          (CASE
            WHEN (a.colC NOT IN ('LM', 'OP', 'QR')) THEN
             (CASE
               WHEN (a.colD IS NULL) THEN
                     a.colD
               WHEN a.colD IS NOT NULL AND ((a.colD < '00') OR (a.colD > '99')) THEN
                    a.colD
             END)

            WHEN (a.colC IN ('LM', 'OP', 'QR')) THEN
             (CASE
               WHEN a.colD IS NULL THEN
                    a.colD 
               WHEN a.colE IS NULL THEN
                    a.colE 
             END)
          END)
       END
  FROM abcdef a
  JOIN maintable m 
    ON a.colfKEY = m.colPKEY 
 WHERE m.colTemp = '999999';
```